# Adding Internal DNS server in Host file

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I have added Global DNS server ip address to one of my Desktop ( please see the Network configuration screenshot ).
[image]

and after that i have added my both domain controller ip address in host file, and it is working fine. ( please see the below screen-shot for your reference )
[image]

Can you please guide, what problem can i face if i kept my configuration in this way.
but i am wondering, can this setting can create a problem?

because the computer will be able to reach corp.abc.com easily, with the help of host file.

Comment: What could you possibly gain from doing this? Just configure your DCs with a global forwarder to those DNS servers if you must.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do this? Apart from it being nonstandard practise, it'll be a management nightmare if your network grows. Your internal clients will also not be able to look up things like service records for your directory.

Use DHCP to assign your addresses, point internal clients to your AD-integrated DNS servers for name resolution, and set up forwarders on your DNS servers. Job done, and no fiddling with hosts files necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a problem if the IP of corp.abc.com changes - In which case you would have to manually update every computer with that host file entry (making it very difficult to maintain if you have more then a couple of computers)

Also - you might need other host entries you don't know about yet, so you could waste a lot of time trying to figure out why something doesn't work.