# Can I log into a Domain account without pointing DNS to the domain controller?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

My situation is as follows:

I have a Windows 2003 Domain Controller which is also my DNS server.  I have 10 Windows XP Pro PC's which all login to domain accounts.  I am about the forward my DNS requests to OPENDNS so I can regulate web access but I have (2) PC's that I would like to keep unregulated.  I manually changed their DNS server IP to (8.8.8.8) which worked but that caused my login to fail (by creating a 3 minute delay before it would let me get to the desktop)  when I change the DNS IP back to the IP of the Domain Controller, everything works smoothly.

Question is, how can I continue to login to the domain but have a different DNS path...is this possible ?

Comment: So you want to break active directory logins to gain some internet filtering?

Answer (score 6):

You can do some trickery with forwarders/stub zones to make this happen, but not in the way that you're looking for. What you really should do is have a local proxy/filter device that can integrate with AD, or have an "unfiltered" VLAN that your local filter ignores.

OpenDNS also has an enterprise filter that integrates with your local AD. I've never used this, but it looks like it can do what you're looking for at a glance.

HOSTS/LMHOSTS hackery is ugly and not scalable and should really be avoided at all costs. It's not a supported configuration and while it might "work", OpenDNS's enterprise offering is less than a dollar a day in your case.

Comment: So I would essentially be taking over the job of content filtering rather than letting OpenDNS do it for me.  Not an option right now as that would require hardware and software.   I think i'm going to start playing around with the HOSTS file and NetBios and see if I can't give the pair of PC's an external DNS IP but still have them contact the Domain Controller...must be a way, there always is.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid you're not going to find another solution, unless you have a separate outbound NAT interface with a separate public IP for just the two clients. There's not really a way to get around the DNS problem that you have. Active Directory **relies** on DNS to work, NetBIOS trickery isn't going to work. A HOSTS file workaround *might* work, but it's dirty and would need *a lot* of entries. Basically, everything in the `_msdcs`zone of your AD DNS.

Comment: Looks like its already been attempted here : http://serverfault.com/questions/423481/adding-internal-dns-server-in-host-file?rq=1  , the same should be fine for me, thanks for your time.

Comment: @user72593 - That's going to be unwieldy, prone to error and untenable in the long run. OpenDNS has a "Business" DNS offering that has AD integration that would probably work for you.

Comment: Hi joeqwerty, I took a look and you are correct.  OpenDNS does have AD integration in their enterprise version of the software but its $25 per user per year, that would cost me $250 a year.  Kind of steep if i'm looking for a 3-5 year solution.  Guess I will try the HOSTS file option and if all else fails i'll have to use a PAC file or something to do my filtering.

Comment: As a note to any others who are looking for a similar scenario, here is what i've found.  When DNS servers are specified, the HOSTS file is not "hit" to determine DC path.  When DNS is NOT specified, it does.  This means you can authenticate to the DC but then you have no internet access (pointless)....however, using the LMHOSTS file and NetBios instead of the HOSTS file, you can solve your issue.   Microsoft's Method : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180094    Good Luck to you all.  As I said...there is always a way.

Comment: @user72593 Just because there is a way doesn't mean it's a good or recommended way. This sounds terrible to manage and troubleshoot

Comment: @user72593 that article is valid for systems up to Windows 2000. It's no guarantee that it will work on modern releases. I highly recommend that people don't implement these kind of crazy ideas!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, I explained that this is a 10 system network, not a multi-subnet enterprise. When someone has 10 PC's, they're looking for a reasonable solution, not one that comes with enterprise costs. Yes, its not a super-duper solution but guess what..Microsoft gave this option and i'm taking it. It WAS made for systems up to Win2K but also works for XP on my setup, I tried it.  Just because I asked a question here doesn't mean i'm incapable of also finding the solution. Thanks for your comments, I posted the solution for others in my situation, not for negative opinions

Comment: If you don't feel that my answer is helpful, you're free to downvote it. Honestly, ~$0.75 for filtering really isn't anything at all, regardless of the size of your business. Just to put things into perspective, I'm I the middle of a project nearing $1mm USD for a 700 employee business. **That** is an enterprise cost, not $250/year. I'm sorry if you disagree, but to me, that's a small price to pay to have your machines in a supported and **correct** configuration. If you're not happy with the feedback you've received, you can always post about it on [meta].

Comment: MDMarra, I don't have a problem with your answer even though its not what I was looking for, its your attitude towards other solutions.  Yes, the one I found DOES work and it WAS provided by Microsoft...so whats your problem?  I have two different DNS paths and didn't have to break AD, solved my problem.  Stop shoving your "its ugly" or "its a hack" or "its not scalable" comments in.  In my network its not ugly at all, Microsoft doesn't call it a hack, and it scaled pretty nicely when I dumped the LMHOSTS file on a shared drive and copied it right over.  DONE !  Some people want THIS solution.

Comment: I think you should re-read the comments and look more closely at who said them. There are three *other* sysadmins that think its an ugly solution besides me. I think you might be assuming that all of those comments are mine. They are not. I'm sorry if you're unhappy with the quality of the feedback that you're getting, but keep in mind that this is a site for professionals and the ones that have commented on this thread have a history of putting a premium on doing things the right way. If you found a workaround that is acceptable to you, no one is stopping you from answering your own question.

Comment: "and it WAS provided by Microsoft" -- yeah. Congratulations you've found an old knowledge base article, now scroll down and check the list of supported platforms under "applies to". I happen to know that the newer Microsoft OSes will ignore those files under certain circumstances. If it's functioning as a workaround for you then that's great, but *it **is** a hack*, sorry, and it's never going to be a good long-term solution to anything other than "how can I make my network less reliable".

Answer (score 0):

If its the DNS server fault please refer to the following links.

[EDNS0 (Extension mechanisms for DNS)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2010/10/11/edns0-extension-mechanisms-for-dns.aspx)

[DNS Forwarders Problems in Windows 2008 R2 DNS Services](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hishamb_msft/archive/2010/09/02/dns-forwarders-problems-in-windows-2008-r2-dns-services.aspx)

Also ensure the correct DNS setting on DC as per [this link](http://abhijitw.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/best-practices-for-dns-client-settings-on-domain-controller/).

If the issue persists post the ipconfig /all and dcdiag /q output of DC.

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe this is a bit obvious, but...

Why wouldn't you just configure your domain controller to forward all external DNS requests to OpenDNS?  That would get you the benefit of the filtering you want, without breaking Active Directory...

Comment: Driftpeasant, I do want to forward all external DNS requests to OpenDNS but I also want to have (2) PC's which are exempt from the filter.  So I would be breaking Active Directory but changing their DNS settings.  In any case, I found the solution to be LMHOSTS/NetBios.  Thanks for your input.